# Which is correct between these two sentences?

Tags: questions, auxiliary-verbs

Context:

> 1: Who the hell **he is**?
>   2: Who the hell **is he**?

I have come across both of them and both of them are spoken frequently, so which is correct grammatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1: Who the hell he is?

is not a question. It is a clause that probably wouldn't stand alone. You could use it like this:

> I don't care **who the hell he is**.

2: is correct as written.